# Pass function from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

I'm a little weak in javascript.
I'm inspiring myself from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-function/) answer to pass a function from parent to child in REACT and I'm having a little difficulty.

Could someone help me correct my code?
Thanks!

```
var List = React.createClass({
  deleting: function(test){
    console.log(test);
  },
  render: function() {      
    var all = this.props.activities;
    var test = List.deleting;
    var list = all.map(function(a){
      return (<ListItem act={a} del={test}>);
    });

    return (
      <ul> {list}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

var ListItem = React.createClass({
  deleting: function(e){
    this.props.del(e.target.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML);
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <li key={this.props.act}>{this.props.act} 
        <div onClick={this.deleting}>X</div>
      </li> 
    );
  }
});
```

The error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need pass reference to method `.deleting` that is part of `List` Object, now you are trying pass var `test = List.deleting;` that is `undefined`. In order to `this` in `.map`, refers to `List`, you should set `this` for `.map` by yourself - to do that just pass (in our case it should be `this` because `this` in render method refers to `List`) second argument to `.map`, and pass to `del=` attribute reference to method `this.deleting`.

Also set `key` attribute for `ListItem`, and in [`React` all tags must be closed](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/self-closing-tag.html) - so add `/>` ( *now you are getting error because you have not closed tag `ListItem`*) in the end of `ListItem` tag

```
var List = React.createClass({
  deleting: function(test) {
    console.log(test);
  },

  render: function() {      
    var all = this.props.activities;
    var list = all.map(function(a) {
      return (<ListItem key={a} act={a} del={this.deleting} />);
    }, this);

    return <ul> {list} </ul>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26036/)