# Passing a parameter from child to parent using prop callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So easily here you can see a way to run a function from the child on the parent

http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/#3-callback-functions

Though how would you go about passing a parameter with the function from the child?

Comment: The same way you pass arguments  to any "other" function: `fn(parameter)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS call parent function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-function)

Answer (score 2):

If you need the state from the parent component, you have to bind his this to the function before passing it.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  callMeMaybe(param) {
    console.log(param)
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <TheChild callMeMaybe={this.callMeMaybe.bind(this)} />
    )
  }
}

class TheChild extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>  
        <button onClick={ event => { 
           this.props.callMeMaybe("message from child") } 
        }>Send a Message to Parent </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/57669/) for you to play with. Check the console after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the bound function from the child with the argument.

```js
const IncrementOne = props => (
  <button onClick={() => props.increment(1)}>
    Increment 1
  </button>
);

const IncrementTwo = props => (
  <button onClick={() => props.increment(2)}>
    Increment 2
  </button>
);

const IncrementX = props => (
  <button onClick={() => props.increment(props.x)}>
    Increment {props.x}
  </button>
);

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }
  
  increment(amount) {
    let counter = this.state.counter + amount;
    this.setState({ counter });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.counter}
        </div>
        <IncrementOne increment={this.increment} />
        <IncrementTwo increment={this.increment} />
        <IncrementX increment={this.increment} x={3} />
        <IncrementX increment={this.increment} x={4} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```