# How to call parent function from child prop without an arg

Tags: reactjs

I'm not looking for [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-function) as I wont be passing in any arg.

I need to call a parent function **without** passing in any args.

**Parent (es6):**

```
foo(){
  ...
  console.log("i was called");
}

<Child callFoo={this.foo} />
```

**Child (es6):**

```
// otherFunc() will be called by an onClick button event
otherFunc(){
 ...

 this.props.callFoo;
}
```

The above does not work. This works but I do not need to do this:

**Parent (es6):**

```
foo(bool){
  ...
  if (bool){
    console.log("i was called");
  }
}

<Child callFoo={this.foo} />
```

**Child (es6):**

```
// otherFunc() will be called by an onClick button event
otherFunc(){
 ...

 this.props.callFoo(true);
}
```

Is there a way to simple call the function by `this.props.callFoo`?

Comment: this.props.callFoo(); That's calling a function without any argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pass a boolean, but you will have to use parenthesis to execute the `callFoo` function. Here's your example:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  foo() {
    console.log('i was called');
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <Child callFoo={this.foo}/>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  otherFunc() {
    this.props.callFoo();
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div onClick={this.otherFunc.bind(this)}>Child</div>
    );
  }

}

React.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```