# React-Chat-Widget props not forwarded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the [react-chat-widget](https://github.com/Wolox/react-chat-widget) and trying to call a function in the base class of my application from a custom component rendered by the `renderCustomComponent` function of the widget.

Here is the code for the base class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Widget, handleNewUserMessage, addResponseMessage, addUserMessage, renderCustomComponent } from 'react-chat-widget';
import 'react-chat-widget/lib/styles.css';
import Reply from './Reply.js';

class App extends Component {

  handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage) => {
      renderCustomComponent(Reply, this.correct);
  }

  correct = () => {
    console.log("success");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Background />
        <Widget
          handleNewUserMessage={this.handleNewUserMessage}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is the code for the custom component `Reply`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Widget, addResponseMessage, renderCustomComponent, addUserMessage } from 'react-chat-widget';

class Reply extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    sendQuickReply = (reply) => {
        console.log(this.props); //returns empty object
        //this.props.correct();  <-- should be called
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="message">
              <div key="x" className={"response"}onClick={this.sendQuickReply.bind(this, "xx")}>xx</div>
            </div>)
    }
}

export default Reply;
```

According to [ReactJS call parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method) this should work. However, when I print the `this.props` object it is empty, although the documentation of the `renderCustomComponent` method states that the second argument of the component to render are the props that the component needs (in this case the parent class function).

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is considered as props, but it is expected to be an object. you would pass it like

```
handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage) => {
      renderCustomComponent(Reply, {correct: this.correct});
}
```