# Props of parent not found in callback sent to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have implemented a callback from the parent to the child component and called it successfully from the child as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method). In my callback, I need the `props` of the parent, the `navigate` prop. But `this.props` in the callback returns `undefined`. How do I get the props object? I don't want to pass the navigation prop onto the child.

Callback:

```
  _onSeperatorPress(item){
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this);
    this.navigation.navigate("main");
  }
```

Parent calling child:

```
    <HorizontalList
      data={genresData}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.description}
      onPress={this._onSeperatorPress} />
```

Child calling callback:

```
<TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => this.props.onPress(item)}
            onShowUnderlay={separators.highlight}
            onHideUnderlay={separators.unhighlight}>
            </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: What’s stopping you to share code wr props is undefined?

Comment: @Think-Twice It is exactly the same as written in the linked answer.

Comment: This looks to be a binding issue from your description. Please check if `this` in the callback is your component's instance.

Comment: @hazardous Yes, it is. How do I solve it?

Comment: i Would recommend you to put the issue code in question itself instead of referring to a source. Two things might be a reason for your issue. Callback has to be blinded in constructor or use arrow function. Perhaps The issue is with scope

Comment: Where the parent is passing change handler in the linked code, do this instead: `<input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.changeHandler.bind(this)} />`. Basically we are pre-binding the change handler to the parent component instance. Now the `this` should be the parent instance and you should be able to access the props etc.

Comment: @Think-Twice I have updated my code.

Comment: did You bind this function _onSeperatorPress in constructor?

Comment: @Think-Twice Yes, that worked.

Comment: No problem Khateeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have binding issues. You need to bind your function in order to access state or props inside the function.

ES5: Normal function and you need to manually bind it in constructor

```
this.handleFunction = this.handleFunction.bind(this);

handleFunction(){
   console.log(this.props); // props are available
}
```

ES6: Arrow function - binding takes automatically and you can stay away with scope related issues

```
handleFunction = () = {
  console.log(this.props); // props are available 
}
```