# How to write a stateless and renderless component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, web-component

I'm new to react and now building a transport web app.. I have a map (with google maps api) component, a user location component and public transport component. Also I wrote a parent component that should manage the state of all three and call the map component to be rendered.

The problem is that I'm not sure I'm doing this right. Actually Im sure that I messed up the way things should work here..

This is my userLocation Component

```
import React from 'react'

export class Userocation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userLatlng = {lat: '', lng: ''}
        };
        this.getUsersLocation = this.getUsersLocation.bind(this)
        this.parseUserLocation = this.parseUserLocation.bind(this)
    }

    parseUserLocation(position) {
        const lat = position.coords.latitude;
        const lng = position.coords.longitude;
        var userLocation = { lat: lat, lng: lng }

        this.props.updateUserLocation(userLocation)
    }

    getUsersLocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.parseUserLocation)
    }

    render() {
        setInterval(this.getUsersLocation, 5000) // Not rendering anything..
    }
}
```

the location manager parent component (I've deleted parts of it so you could see the problem) -

```
import React from 'react'
import userLocation from './userLocation'
import busStationLocation from './busStaionLocation'

export class Locationmanager extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            userLocation: {lat: '', lng: ''},
            loadingUserLocation: true,
        }
    }

    updateUserLocation(newLocation) {
        this.setState({userLocation: newLocation})
    }

    render() {
        <userLocation /> //Rendering a component that doesn't present nothing..
        //calling the map and transport component...
    }
}
```

do you see the problem? I dont understand how to organise my components..

Comment: rendered components must start with upper case letter

Comment: you are right , but its just an example, I'm talking about the concept of how organise this..

Comment: Really haven't defined a specific problem

Comment: Maybe there isnt.. Its just doesnt seems right to me to call setInterval in the render function..

Comment: Agree there. That is a bad idea. And a render() has to return something

Comment: So how would you do this?

Comment: Start an interval in componentDidMount and clear it in componentWillUnmount. Then should setState when you have new data and if you change child props use componentDidUpdate

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your example (I don't see why those are two different components) but if you want a component that just handles logic, it sound like you want a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)? In it, you'd have all your logic handling, then it would render return its children (with any pertinent data passed as props). So any of your components that actually render something which need the same data would be wrapped in it.

Comment: You might also want to look at [passing callbacks properties to child components from parents to modify parent state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method). Again not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for but it might help you in thinking about React's one-way data flow (and how to sort of get around then when necessary)

Comment: You can always `return null` in the render() to make it a viewless component.