# React Tabs and selectedIndex

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React Tabs (https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs) in controlled mode.

Setting the `tabIndex` in a parent Component:

```
this.setState({
    tabIndex: 1,
});
```

And passing the `tabIndex` through in the properties:

```
<TabContents tabIndex={this.state.tabIndex} />
```

Putting the component into "controlled mode":

```
export default class TabContents extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tabIndex: 0
        }

    }

    ...

    render() {

        <Tabs selectedIndex={this.props.tabIndex} onSelect={tabIndex => this.setState({ tabIndex })}>

    ...

    }
}
```

This works and the second tab (with a `tabIndex` of 1) is selected.

However when I click on any other tab, nothing happens. It's stuck on the `tabIndex` of 1. **How do I go about allowing to switch tabs when in "controlled mode"?**

## Full JSX:

```
<Tabs selectedIndex={this.props.tabIndex} onSelect={tabIndex => this.setState({ tabIndex })}>
    <TabList>
        <Tab>Accounts <span className="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{this.props.selectedSource ? this.props.sources[sourceIndex].accounts.length : 0}</span></Tab>
        <Tab>Forms</Tab>
    </TabList>

    <TabPanel>
        {this.props.activeDetails ? this.props.activeDetails.make : null }

        {accounts && (
            <ul className="accounts-list list-group">{accounts}</ul>
        )}

        {disabled_accounts && (
            <ul className="accounts-list disabled list-group">{disabled_accounts}</ul>
        )}

    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel>
        <h2>Forms</h2>
        {this.props.activeDetails ? this.props.activeDetails.make : null }
    </TabPanel>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: You are using `selectedIndex={this.props.tabIndex}` and setting into state, I think you need to use `this.state.tabIndex`.

Comment: I want to set the `selectedIndex` in the parent controller, which is why I am using `this.props.tabIndex`

Comment: Can you add full JSX?

Comment: Added the full JSX

Comment: You need to create one method into parent component maintain state there and onSelect={tabIndex => //call parent method}

Comment: Ahhh ok. Thanks. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <Tabs selectedIndex={this.props.tabIndex} onSelect={tabIndex => this.setState({ tabIndex })}>
```

As per your question you have multiple child components, But on select you are changing the local state `onSelect={tabIndex => this.setState({ tabIndex })}`

What you need to do?

1. You need to create one method in parent component
2. Pass that props to children components
3. on children `onSelect` call that parent method

Now, parent will be responsible for active tab.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180068/2630817) of calling parent from child.

Answer (score 0):

As per your above comments you need to save with parent and child components values..

so you can use state and constructors is very effective..

No need to send parameters to parent . you can access the state value from the parent .