# How to let a function run after react component construct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to let func run after Component A constructor in react. When I debugger blow codes, the func be to called first, then the A constructor, but in my case I want to the opposite, how can I do it?

```
function func() {
    return 'aa'
}
class A extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)   
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  } 
}

class App extends Component {   
  render() {
    return (
      <A>
        {func()}
      </A>
    )   
  }
```

}

Comment: `constructor(props) {
    super(props); func();
  }` ?

Comment: You could call it within the constructor for example, or inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: the problem is you are invoking func in app, i would have checked the type of children and if its a function, invoke this.props.children()

Comment: Call your function inside `componentDidMount` method it only runs once after the first render

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS call parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method)

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this, but I would have done something like this:

```
    function func() {
    return 'aa'
}

class A extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)   
  }

  render() {
    return( <div>
      {typeof this.props.children === 'function' ? this.props.children() : 
       this.props.children}
    </div>)
  } 
}

class App extends Component {   
  render() {
    return (
      <A>
        {func}
      </A>
    )   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
class A extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)   
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.func();
  }

  func() {
    // this will run once when component A runs
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  } 
}

class App extends Component {   
  render() {
    return (
    <A></A>
    )   
  } 
}
```

This way, when component App runs, it will trigger the componentWillMount method in component A, which will call the func() function.

Comment: you should write UNSAFE_componentWillMount() and stop using it as react recommend it