# Is it possible to pass the setState method as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the setState method to a functional component and access it from there.

On class component

```
<InputRender name2={this.state.name2} setState={this.setState}/>
```

Functional component

```
import React from 'react';
export const InputRender=(props)=>{
return(
        <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => { props.setState({ name2: e.target.value }); }}
        value={props.name2} />
    )
}
```

When trying to change the input while running I'm getting this error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'enqueueSetState' of undefined**

I know there can be many workarounds for this and I can implement them but I want to know if this achievable and if not then why.

Comment: That's not from where the error comes from.

Comment: the state used in the same component or the file props used in other file props.setState cont find

Comment: Just an advice, please complete the JS training before you jump to ReactJS. This is the basic concept of how `this` keyword works in JS and if you would have simply searched the error you posted here then you would have got your answer. Expecting this from you next time, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the setState function.

```
setState={this.setState.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the name that exists in React by default, I would suggest to use some custom name:-

Something similar to what you did but different format

```js
_updateName = (newName) => {
  this.setState({ name2: newName });
}

<InputRender name2={this.state.name2} updateName={this._updateName}/>
```

**Functional Component**

```js
import React from 'react';
export const InputRender=(props)=>{
return(
        <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => { props.updateName(e.target.value); }}
        value={props.name2} />
    )
}
```

Hope this helps!

FYI, you can still make your changes work if you bind `setState` method to point to your class only, like

```js
<InputRender name2={this.state.name2} setState={this.setState.bind(this)}/>
```

But I would not recommend this

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the setState in a function in parent component and then you can pass function as props to child component.
   You can refer [ReactJS call parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method)