# Why does my React form auto-refresh the page even if I put "event.preventDefault()" on handleSubmit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have two files which work together to render things. The first is App.js, which first renders Form.js. The form will then collect information, which on submission, changes the Form state and calls a function from App.js. This function is called "createProject." Calling "createProject" in Form.js "handleSubmit" makes the page auto-refresh. However, if I remove "createProject" from handleSubmit, the page does not auto-refresh. Here are the two files.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Project from "./components/Project.js"
import Form from "./Form.js";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectList: [],
            myProjects: [],
            userList: [],
            submitted: false
        };

        this.createProject = this.createProject.bind(this);
    }

    createProject(title, desc, langs, len, exp) {
        this.setState({
            projectList: this.state.projectList.push([
                {
                    title : title,
                    description : desc,
                    language : langs,
                    length : len,
                    experience : exp
                }
            ]),
            submitted : true
        });
    }

    deleteProject(title) {
        const projects = this.state.projectList.filter(
            p => p.title !== title 
        );
        this.setState({projects});
    }

    render() {
        let info;
        if (this.state.submitted) {
            info = (
                <div>
                  <p>cccc</p>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            info = (
                <br/>
            );
        }
        return(
            <div>
                <Form/>
                {info}
                {this.state.projectList.map((params) =>
                <Project {...params}/>)}
            </div>
        );
    }

    
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import createProject from "./App.js"

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        title: "",
        description: "",
        language: "",
        length: 0,
        experience: "",
        submitted: false
      };
  
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {

      this.setState({
        submitted: true
      })
      createProject(
        this.state.title, 
        this.state.description,
        this.state.language,
        this.state.length,
        this.state.experience
      )
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  
    handleInputChange(event) {
      const target = event.target;
      const value = target.value;
      const name = target.name;
  
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    }
  
    render() {
      let info;
      if (this.state.submitted) {
        info = (
          <div>
            <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
            <p>{this.state.description}</p>
            <p>{this.state.language}</p>
            <p>{this.state.length}</p>
            <p>{this.state.experience}</p>
           </div>
        );
      } else {
          info = <br/>;
      }
      return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Title:
                <input
                name="title"
                type="textbox"
                checked={this.state.title}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                Description:
                <input
                name="description"
                type="textbox"
                checked={this.state.description}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                Language:
                <input
                name="language"
                type="textbox"
                checked={this.state.language}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                Length:
                <input
                name="length"
                type="number"
                checked={this.state.length}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                Experience:
                <input
                name="experience"
                type="textbox"
                checked={this.state.experience}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          {info}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default Form;
```

I've also tried adding "new" to the "createProject" in handleSubmit, and while that does stop the auto-refresh, it will not call the createProject function. (Or maybe it does, but none of the code in the createProject function seems to be run.) Can anyone help with preventing this auto refresh while also allowing App's createProject function to run properly?

Comment: Duplicate of [ReactJS call parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page auto refreshes because execution never gets to your `event.PreventDefault()` line. This is due to an error encountered when react tries to evaluate `createProject`. To fix this, correct `handleSubmit` like so.

```
handleSubmit(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); // moved up in execution.

  this.setState({
    submitted: true
  })
  createProject(
    this.state.title, 
    this.state.description,
    this.state.language,
    this.state.length,
    this.state.experience
  )
}
```

Notice that moving `event.PreventDefault()` to the top of your `handleSubmit(event)` function just before `this.setState` line prevents default form behaviour on submit.

You however get an error because App.js doesn't export a function called createProject. To maintain the `createProject` within `App` instance, you need to pass it as a `prop` which you can then reference as `this.props.createProject`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180068/10520928) on how to do call a Parent method in ReactJS.