# React - Accessing child ref of parent from another child

Tags: reactjs

I try to call methods of ref of parent from a child component. I can explain my question as follows:

```
class Parent {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.refOfChild= React.createRef();
   }

    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <AnotherChild refOfChildWithRef = {this.refOfChild }/>
                <ChildWithRef ref={ this.refOfChild}  />

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to call some method from `AnotherChild`

```
class AnotherChild {
     onClickSomeButton(){
           this.props.refOfChildWithRef.current.someMethod();
    }

}
```

Normally, I can call this `someMethod` from  `Parent` successfully but I could not do it from `AnotherChild`.

Hoping that I could explain my question.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why use ref when you can simply do by callback method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method

Comment: Because I have many method to call. Passing each to each child is very exhaustive.

Comment: You might want to look at something like Redux and/or a state management system to be able to share functions between components.

Comment: Is there a system which matches my situation including ref stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should explore the concept of ref forwarding. Link is as below:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

**Ref forwarding is an opt-in feature that lets some components take a ref they receive, and pass it further down (in other words, “forward” it) to a child.**

I believe this is the only thing you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can structure things to get the method from another component with refs, although I have never seen or done it this way, I would love to test it here **(See Below Method 2)**.

Normally you would have the function that is accessible to be at the top level and then pass that down to each component.

```
<App>
const appFunction = () => {...
<Child1 appFunction={appFunction} />
<Child2 appFunction={appFunction} />
</App>
```

Click the button below **"Run Code Snippet"** to see how the code should work.

That said, if you're looking to forward the refs, you can use the following:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

---

**Method 1:** Passing Functions As Props

```js
// main.js

const ChildOne = props => {
  const onClickButton = () => {
    props.parentFunction('child one');
  }
  return <div><button onClick={onClickButton}>Click Me - From Child One</button></div>
};

const ChildTwo = props => {
  const onClickButton = () => {
    props.parentFunction('child two');
  }
  return <div><button onClick={onClickButton}>Click Me - From Child Two</button></div>
}

const App = () => {
  const parentFunction = (text) => {
    console.log('PARENT FUNCTION Run From: ', text);
  }
  
  return <div>
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <ChildOne parentFunction={parentFunction} />
    <ChildTwo parentFunction={parentFunction} />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Method 2:** Attempting To Use Refs

I think the reason why (and I still need to investigate this) is that this isn't recommended because of potential performance issues. I noticed when I did this, it would load the entire component into the other component, which is a bit cyclical when it comes to looking at state changes.

```js
const { createRef } = React;

class ChildOne extends React.Component {
  myFunction() {
     console.log('hello from Child 1');
  }
  
  render () {
    return (<div>Child One</div>);
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.refOfChild = React.createRef();
      this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
  }

  clickMe() {
    this.props.forwardRef.current.myFunction();
  }

  render () {
    return (<div>Child Two<br /><button onClick={this.clickMe}>Child 2 Button</button></div>);
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.refOfChild = React.createRef();
  }
  
  render () {
    return (<div><h1>Parent</h1><br /><ChildOne ref={this.refOfChild} /><br /><ChildTwo forwardRef={this.refOfChild} /></div>)
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I used method 1 but  I do not know why I received 'null reference' error for method 2.

Comment: When you debug and comment out certain code, can you identify where the error is happening?